# The parameters 'file' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file are missing or invalid

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using STS version 3.9. I am trying to add external dependency for ojdbc7.jar to local maven repository. I have downloaded  `ojbdc7.jar` from oracle site. Through configuration window 
I have set goal as - `install:install-file`

Parameters as -

```
-Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc7.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

While running this, I am getting below error.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (default-cli) on project .The parameters 'file' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file are missing or invalid
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `ojdbc.jar` available on your machine? If yes, at what location?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all the parameters in the single quotes. shell is expanding it in unacceptable ways to maven.

```sh
mvn install:install-file -Dfile='/path/library.jar' -DgroupId='groupid' \
  -DartifactId='' -Dversion='' -Dpackaging='jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the value of your param:

```
-Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc7.jar}
```

to the exact location of the jar you've downloaded -

```
-Dfile={/Users/user/Downloads/ojdbc7.jar}
```

**Note**: It must be a valid path in your system which you can get by looking at the properties/info of the downloaded jar.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already downloaded ojdbc7.jar and it is resume folder on desktop. I have given path for jar as below - 
-Dfile = "C:\Users\vijay\Desktop\Resume" .                                                
 Still facing same error.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the file path and double quotes:

```
mvinstall:install-file -Dfile="path/file.jar" -DgroupId="com.oracle" -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion="12.1.0" -Dpackaging=jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to add the backslash like so:

```
mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile='some-file.jar' \
-DgroupId='com.something' \
-DartifactId='artifactId' \
-Dversion='version' \
-Dpackaging='packaging' \
-DgeneratePom=true
```